# how to pass the likes of my url for facebook page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

put the Like button code for data-href = "myurl.com" already has 3,000 likes, today we have a page on facebook www.facebook.com / MyURL wonder if it is possible to migrate these 3,000 likes to myurl.com facebook.com / MyURL to not have to start from scratch again!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope you can't do that. It's like me liking one page and then you moving these likes to some other page which I didn't manually like.

Best bet is to post a message and say that this is the new page and ask people to go and like it.

Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If this is possible here it is...

Ok so this is truly just a shot in the dark based on Facebook 'SQL' Im still learning facebook query language and I do not know if this would some how break a law or paramater I am unaware of but what if you attempted the like FQL GET but called transposed the objects ( being link and page) versus user id. EXAMPLE : `SELECT ... FROM like WHERE object_id = A`SELECT ... FROM like WHERE post_id = B SELECT ... FROM like WHERE user_id = C`

> SELECT user_id FROM like WHERE object_id="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
>
> SELECT user_id, object_id, post_id FROM like WHERE user_id=mine() -> redirect link out or put your web address on the page and comply by the TOS ( MY PERSONAL SUGGESTION)

[Click Here For The FB DEV Blog Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/)

Hope that Helps

Im pretty sure anything else is outside the TOS, but I could be wrong get creative.